# How to uninstall spotifyd and spotifytui

Tags: command-line, uninstall

I did the whole setup of spotifytui with spotifyd but now I want to uninstall it. How to do it?

Comment: ,,,same as you've installed it. :~)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to uninstall both.

To uninstall spotify-tui:

```
sudo snap remove spt
```

To uinstall spotifyd:

```
sudo rm -r spotifyd/
```